# How to seal a window on stucco?

Tags: windows, waterproofing, sealing, window-frame

I have this window on a stucco wall:

[image]

Once when it rained a lot I saw standing water in the window frame (I could only slowly dry it out with rags). I am worried that water seeps into the wall, compromising the wood and wet insulation causing mold grow.

Upson closer inspection, there are many cracks around the window. Let me zoom into the bottom right corner:

[image]

I can even push into the lower bar (where the red arrow points to) and the crack would become bigger. It doesn't feel like wood but vinyl or similar.

What can I do to seal all of these cracks and make sure water doesn't get in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sort of outdoor caulk will do.  Buy a caulk gun if you don't have one, and follow the prep and application instructions.  You should clean the area and pry out any loose caulk or paint, and work the caulk into the cracks.  (Note that 100% silicone caulks are not paintable, and that you need to leave any weep holes - such as the one in the pic appears to be - to allow condensation to escape and a little air to pass between inside and outside.)

Comment: Thanks! I have a caulk gun. Since you say silicone not paintable, would you recommend Acrylic Latex instead? How about this Behr White Elastomeric Window & Door Sealant https://www.homedepot.com/p/316993429. And prying out loose caulk, would you do this with a putty knife?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry so slow to answer, have been offline since then.  Let us know how it turns out!

Comment: To clarify, yes to all 3 questions, although the usual way to work the caulk into the cracks is with a wet finger.  A vinyl, latex, or neoprene glove is optional.